# How edit placeholder by pressing button? (JQuery) - EDIT

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, placeholder

I have actually some problems with my script and don't know at all how I could solve my problem. I would like to have an edit mode by pressing a buton,then my `<input type="text">` will be abled to be edit.

And when I press Cancel, then the value previously written in the placeholder, keep the same value.

Here is the fiddle to be more clear :

```js
$('button#editMode').click(function() {
  $(this).css("display", "none");
  $("button#validEdit").css("display", "inline");
  $("button#cancelEdit").css("display", "inline");
  $("input[name='Field']").prop("disabled", false);

});

var prevanswer =

  $('button#cancelEdit').click(function() {
    $("button#validEdit").css("display", "none");
    $("button#cancelEdit").css("display", "none");
    $("button#editMode").css("display", "inline");
    $("input[name='Field']").prop("disabled", true);

  });


$('button#validEdit').click(function() {
  var answer = $("input[name='Field']").val();
  $("input[name='Field']").val("");
  $("input[name='Field']").prop("disabled", true);
  $('input[name="Field"]').attr("placeholder", answer);
});
```

```css
#validEdit {
  display: none;
}

#cancelEdit {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="editMode"> Edit Mode </button>
<button id="validEdit"> Confirm </button>
<button id="cancelEdit"> Cancel </button>

<input name="Field" placeholder="Value" type="text" disabled>
```

And here is my problem, I don't know at all, how I can do =(
If you can help me, it would be great. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('button#validEdit').click(function() {
    var $field = $('input[name="Field"]');
    $field.data('oldPlaceholder', $field.attr('placeholder');
    $field.attr("placeholder", "Type your answer here");
});
```

then to restore to old placeholder

```
$('button#cancelEdit').click(function() {
    var $field = $('input[name="Field"]');
    $field.attr("placeholder", $field.data('oldPlaceholder'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! I re-edit my code because I just progress on hit a little bit. The last problem is about the Cancel button, i don't know how to keep the older placeholder.